# How to integrate a source compiled LLVM with Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, llvm

As part of a research project at school, I'm exploring mobile specific energy optimizations and am building infrastructure to test these optimizations on a popular mobile platform. Given my background in LLVM, I have decided to setup the testing infrastructure around the iOS platform. I thought that since Xcode already uses LLVM under the hood, it should be easy to integrate a copy of LLVM compiled from source into the Xcode toolchain, but I haven't been able to find an option to accomplish it in Xcode yet. (I'm new to OSX and haven't worked with Xcode before)

Am I overlooking anything, or is such an integration not supported out of the box in Xcode?

Comment: You could probably redefine the build-rules for the project that is using the compiler to use a different one; but again, its quite a bit of effort. There is no support in XCode natively to change the compiler toolchains outside of the ones that are bundled with it.

Comment: You can always compile your code outside of Xcode in a shared library, and then have a dummy project that wrapped this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for obfuscater-llvm, but it should work for a "normal" llvm:

https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki/Installation#integration-into-xcode